# Error occurred during execution of the database script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I pushed a commit to git, and when I tried publishing the site, I get this error

> 'Web deployment task failed.(An error occurred during execution of the
>   database script.The error occurred between the following lines of the
>   script: 4264 and 4279. "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT*FROM[_EFMIGRATIONHISTO"
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column ' '.

[image]

I have searched everywhere and I cannot find a solution, and now I'm getting the 'Site Under Construction' error when I try my site's URL.

Answer (score 0):

From the error:

- You have a table Called 'Notes'
- You are trying to insert some data in the 'Notes' table
- The migration script is trying to insert data but the value for the 'PrescriberId' column is null in your migration script

Try to put a value for the 'PrescriberId' or set the 'Identity Increment' property of the 'PrescriberId' column to 1 so that it generates an id while inserting the data.